# Enum within structure : comparison between '' and 'enum <anonymous>

Tags: gcc, enums, typecasting-operator

typedef enum

```
{

    var1,var2

}enum1;

 typedef enum 

{

  var3,var4 = 8

}enum2;

struct struct1

{

  enum1 e1;

  enum2 e2;

};

int main()

{

  struct struct1 *s1;


  if (s1 -> e1 == var4)
```

This code throws the warning :

comparison between 'enum1' and 'enum ' [-Wenum-compare].

Though after reading [Set one enum equal to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899491/set-one-enum-equal-to-another), and changing the code as

> s1 -> e1 ==(enum1) (int)var4

I m unable to resolve.

Some suggestions to clear warning will be of great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Can converting both var to int type works?
Or use the -Wno-enum-compare compiler option

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.4.5 doesn't warn with the stated code change.